# Queueing: N producers to N consumers

Tags: python, queue, message-queue, beanstalkd

The requirement is as follows:

- There are N producers, that generate messages or jobs or whatever you want to call it.
- Messages from each procuder must be processed in order and each message must be processed exactly once.
- There's one more restriction: at any time for any given producer there must be not more than one message that is being processed.
- The consuming side consists of a number of threads (they are identical in their functionality) that are spread across a number of processes - it is a WSGI application run via mod_wsgi.

At the moment, the queueing on the consuming side is implemented as a custom queue, that subclasses [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html), but it has its own problems that I won't get into, the main one being that upon process restart its queue is lost.

Is there a product, that will make it possible to fulfill the requirements I've outlined above? Support for persistency would've been great, though that is not *so* important (since the queue will not reside in the worker process' memory any more).

Comment: [celery](http://celeryproject.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many products that do what you are looking for.  People with Django experience will probably tell you "celery", but that's not a complete answer.  Celery is a (useful) wrapper around the actual queuing system, and using a wrapper doesn't mean you don't have to think about your underlying technology.

ZeroMQ, Redis, and RabbitMQ are a few different solutions that come to mind.  There are of course more options.  I'm fairly certain that no queueing solution will support your "at any time for any given producer there must be not more than one message that is being processed" requirement as a configuration parameter; you should probably implement this requirement at the producer (i.e. do not submit job #2 until you receive confirmation that job #1 has completed).

Redis is not a real queueing system, but a very fast database with pub/sub features; you would not be able to use Redis pub/sub to satisfy the "job processed exactly once" requirement out of the box, although you could use Redis pub/sub to publish jobs to a single subscriber which then pushes them into the database as a list (a poor man's queue).  Your consumers would then atomically pull a job from the list.  It'll work if you want to go this route.

RabbitMQ is an "enterprise" queueing system, and would absolutely meet your requirements, but you'd have to deploy the RabbitMQ server somewhere, and it might be overkill.  For the record, I use RabbitMQ on numerous projects, and it gets the job done.  Set up a "direct"-type exchange, bind it to a single queue, and subscribe all your consumers to this queue.  You get pretty good persistence from RabbitMQ too.

ZeroMQ has a very very flexible queueing model, and ZeroMQ can absolutely be made to do what you want. ZeroMQ is basically just the transport mechanism though, so when it comes to making your publishers and subscribers and a broker to distribute them, you may end up rolling your own.